# Firebase cloud messaging for iOS works on local build but not for Testflight

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having an issue with FCM and iOS testflight builds (and I assume app store release builds as well). Push notifications work when building the flutter app with a local physical test iphone 11. The device registers and we store the token in a database. When I subsequently send a push to the device it works fine. But when I archive the app and distribute it to testflight notifications stop working. I delete the tokens from our database, delete the test local build and then install the newly published testflight app, which on opening registers a token in the database as it should. On sending a test message I am presented with this error

The message could not be delivered to the device identified by <token_id_here>.

```
Although the token is syntactically correct, it is not known to the Firebase
project you are using. This could have the following reasons:

- The token has been unregistered from the project. This can happen when a user
  has logged out from the application on the given client, or if they have
  uninstalled or re-installed the application.

- The token has been registered to a different Firebase project than the project
  you are using to send the message. A common reason for this is when you work
  with different application environments and are sending a message from one
  environment to a device in another environment.
```

I do not believe that it is the first case, since we do not have a call to invalidate that token anywhere in our codebase.

We believe it to have something to do with the second case. One of our project managers moved the project between owners.

It is pertinent to note that Android works everywhere, local physical device builds and internal testing track on the app store.

I am sending test push notifications using the kreait/firebase-php package and this is my code to send the notifications.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->service = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount(storage_path('app/google-service-account.json'));
    $this->messaging = $this->service->createMessaging();
}
```

```
    public function setReminder($msg, $title)
    {
        $body = Str::limit($msg, 400);

        $this->payload = [
            'notification' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $body,
            ],
            
            'android' => [
                'priority' => 'HIGH',
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => $title,
                    'body' => $body,
                    'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                    'color' => '#33b0b3',
                ],
            ],

            'apns' => [
                'headers' => [
                    'apns-priority' => '10',
                    'apns-collapse-id' => 'reminder',
                ],
                'payload' => [
                    'aps' => [
                        'alert' => [
                            'title' => $title,
                            'body' => $body,
                        ],
                        'sound' => 'default',
                        'content-available' => 1,
                    ],
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }
```

```
    public function send(string $device)
    {
        $this->payload['token'] = $device;

        return $this->messaging
            ->send($this->payload);
    }
```

Which is then called like this:

```
    Fcm::setReminder(
        trans('user.push.reminders.module_part2_reminder'),
        'Pulse Reminder');
    Fcm::send($device->token);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default applications launched in local device use `development` as entitlements. This means using apple sandbox and relative token.

While using testflight automatically uses `production`: so you need to switch the server configuration to use different certificates and server